# virtualenv is not picking python3 automatically from /usr/bin

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, ubuntu-18.04

I have installed new ubuntu 18.4 and while solving some other error while installing requirements through pip. I tried installing `python-setuptools` and `python-dev` instead of installing `python3-setuptools` and `python3-dev` which in turn installed python2.7 on my machine. Well the solution didn't work and I removed the packages as I don't want 2.7 on my machine and now when I run the following command:
`sudo virtualenv venv` 
I get this message: `The path python2 (from --python=python2) does not exist.`
before installing python-dev and python-setup tools the above command worked fine.

I have tried replacing `python` symbolic link to `python3.6` in `/usr/bin`.
by executing: `ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python` although I am able to get python3.6 console every time run `python` like on fresh install of ubuntu but I can't creat virtual environment the same way.

Comment: use command `python3`, install vitualbox as `python4 -m pip install virtualbox` process like this

Answer (score 1):

Try yo run it with this specific python

`/usr/bin/python3.6 -m pip install virtualenv`

`sudo /usr/bin/python3.6 -m virtualenv venv`

and delete the python2.7 is probably a bad idea cause there is probably thing that using it on your machine, and also, consider reading about system envirmate varibles, as `PATH` for example that would solve you problem